# Proximity Sensor

Tags: sensor, light, sound

I am trying to make a circuit that as an object moves closer to a proximity sensor it triggers a dimmer switch controlling a light and amplifier for loudspeakers.

Basically as an object moves closer to the sensor the sound and light will get more.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to electronics.stackexchange. What have you tried so far? Can you edit a circuit diagram into your question? Which specific parts of the task are causing you the most difficulty?

Comment: Are you looking for a component that does that? Or do you want to build it from discrete parts?

Comment: The different components or overview of how this would work?

Answer (score 1):

> **The different components or overview of how this would work?**

First you should choose a sensor (or at least a sensor type). These vary greatly in price and capabilities. For example

- [HC-SR-04](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/30209) - inexpensive, poor range.
- [SW-MINIPB](http://www.skpang.co.uk/catalog/mini-push-button-switch-p-540.html) - very cheap, especially in bulk. Range very very small.
- [E-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_E-3_Sentry) - expensive but good range.

You'll need some sort of circuit to connect this sensor up to. This circuit depends greatly on which of the above sensors you selected. This space is too small for me to produce compete schematics for all of them so I'll just say you may want to consider a microcontroller

The sensor circuit will need to communicate with a sound and light control unit. You should choose a communications medium. For example:

- wires carrying a small on-off voltage
- wires carrying a serial protocol
- Ethernet
- WiFi
- XBee
- other

For some of these your sensor and control circuits may need to incorporate additional elements. For some of them you might be able to choose a microcontroller with
suitable in-built capabilities (depends on distances etc)

Your controller will need to communicate with the sound and light switches, unless you choose to have your sensor circuit communicate directly with them. The choice may depend on the cost and complexity of your chosen communication medium for the sensor. You might choose to make use of an off-the-shelf remote-control power switch - in which case you'll design your controller to communicate with that.

You'll need a suitable device to switch on your lamp and klaxon/HiFi/Radio/Whatever. You could choose an existing off-the shelf solution (I'd Google "home automation", "X10" but you may have different ideas/needs). You could instead build your own, in which case you'll need to select relays, opto-isolators (or equivalent) maybe microcontrollers etc. Again, this space is too small to enumerate all the possible options.

Comment: You're linking to E3-Sentry aircraft.  Is this what you want to do?

Comment: @Scott: If user28794's first name is Barrack and the objects whose proximity he wants to measure are [SU-30](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Republic_of_Iran_Air_Force#Jane.27s_Sentinel_Estimate_of_Units_1993)s then that would be an appropriate sensor - no? ;-)

Comment: I've used the E-3 sensor and can vouch for its effectiveness against most things especially threats LOL